# pimp up a plain jar to be a maven jar with internal pom.xml for Artifactory

Tags: java, maven-2, pom.xml, artifactory

I need to use a xyz.jar wich was generated with ant. Hence, the transitive dependencies are missing. So I had the idea, to modify the xyz.jar to add the internal META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml and pom.properties files.

When I deployed it to Artifactory, it ignored them and generated it's own pom.xml without dependencies.

What has one to do, Artifactory deploys the pom.xml lying about in the same folder as the xyz.jar file?

Lost way too much time on this allready...

Comment: Why not using Ivy to handle the dependencies or use Maven instead.

Comment: I use maven for my project, which needs xyz.jar, which was created with ant. I want to tell artifactory/maven, which are the transitive dependencies xyz.jer needs, without adding the transitive dependencies to my project's pom.xml

Comment: You have to create the pom with the dependencies for your xyz.jar otherwise it will not work. You can create this pom manually and add to your Ant project and during the deployment you can add the pom as well.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that Artifactory skips the deployment of the internal POM because it cannot read the POM's physical size from the archive (done for historical reasons); You can verify this by looking at the log for a warning message along the lines of:

> "Found pom.xml file with size -1 inside the zip. Ignoring"

If you've already gone to the lengths of creating a customized POM file, you can paste it's contents in the POM content editor of the artifact deployer or deploy it independently; though the first option will give you the benefit of auto detecting the deployment coordinates for the JAR file.

Comment: I have looked in the tomcat logfiles, but did not find an entry similar to the one you mentioned here. Mayby I will give it a try later on, but I am in the hot "end of project phase", only happy to have it running in the moment....

Answer (score 0):

It might be a better idea to add it's dependencies to your pom instead of rigging a third-party library to use maven.

That being said, make sure your pom.xml is valid XML (most modern IDEs can validate xml for  you) and make sure your properties file includes version, group id, and artifact id.

Artifactory has changed the way that it handles POM generation in different versions, so, depending on your version, you may have some sort of generate pom option that you have to turn off on deploy. I think they have a deploy time pom editor or something like that in the newer versions.

Comment: it's an inhouse library, so it's not too bad. when i have to adopt it one day, maybe i will migrate it to a maven setup...

Answer (score 0):

modify the ant that create an xyz.jar to produce runnable jar - the jar should have all its deppendencies packaged inside.(create a lib directory in your xyz project and put all the jars xyz deppends on inside this directory, then export your project to jar with all the libraries packaged inside)
good step-by-step example how to create an ant script can be found [here](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-build-executable-jar-file-reference-dependencies).

good luck!